# Help finding a children's book about giants

Tags: identification-request

A fully drawn book from the 90s in the UK.

It was a book about giants. It was, to me, the other giants story alongside BFG. Definitely a different style, and theme. I remember scenes in the book taking place at night, in suburbs, with all the lights of the houses under the moon. Possibly on the cover, which I think was dark. I remember the book being large, and portrait orientation.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to LitSE. You've already provided a fair bit of detail, which is great, but there's a pretty comprehensive list of [id request prompts](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) on the wiki, too. Could you go through those as well and add what you can? It's surprising what small details can be useful.

Comment: Do any of these ring a bell? [Diane Goode's Book of Giants and Little People](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0525456600); [When the Giants Came to Town](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0590468928); [The Giant of Jum](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0590468928); [A Tale of Two Giants](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/12578457)? Finally, this one is not 90s, but it looks very similar to your suggestion: [The Boy and the Giant](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1419733184), by David Litchfield.

Comment: @elutionary thanks! Alas none of them are correct but gosh you are right, that last one is a good fit. However I think the drawing style was less stylised than that, and a little more "realistic"